# no instance of overloaded function matches the specified type (C++)

Tags: c++, error-handling, constructor

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class student {
private:
    string sname;
    float gpa;
public:
    student(string name, float g = 0.0);
    ~student();
};

struct student {
    string name;
    int gpa;

    void display();
};

student::student(string name, float g) { // **this is where I get the error**
    cout << "student constructor is running..." << endl;
    student stu;
    stu.name += name;
    stu.gpa = g;
}

student::~student() {
    // cout << "Student No." << endl;
    cout << "student destructor is running..." << endl;
}

void student::display() {
    cout << "Student Name: " << name << endl;
    cout << "Student GPA: " << gpa << endl;
}
```

It is a student header file.
The error came out: no instance of constructor "student::student" matches the argument list.
I don't get it why and how to fix this.

Comment: Why do you have both a class and a struct with the same name?

Comment: I don't think you understand constructors. You're creating an instance of `student` _inside the student constructor_ (and try to use an empty constructor that doesn't exist) when that really is the constructor's job. For some reason, you've redefined `student` as a `struct` and a `class` which should be giving its own error. You include `<iostrem>` which doesn't exist (though that may have been a typo when creating this post because that's a fatal error that the compiler has to show). You try to use `stu.name` but the first definition of `student` uses `sname`, not `name`.

Comment: Gonna just assume `#include <iostrem>` is supposed to be `#include <iostream>`. It helps if you actually paste from the real code. you can't typo if you don't actually type. Regardless, your code should look [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/8G6s1xjWv).

Comment: ODR violation, you have 2 class/struct `student`. Error might not point to the actual cause of the error though :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

compiler think student as structure,
change student sturture name

Answer (score 0):

Actually struct is similar with class only that all its members are implicitly public (instead of private). So you have double definition for "student" class (one defined with class so it is private and one defined with struct so it is public). As a result when you try to define the constructor for the first class the compiler do not found its declaration in the second public "student" class.
In the same time my compiler (MSVS2019) detects double student definition and reports it (it is true that double definition is reported after complaining about "no instance ..."):

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
--------    ----    ----------- ------- ----    ----    -----------------
Error   E0493   no instance of overloaded function "student::student" matches the specified type    Test    C:\Users\Projects\MSVC19\Tests\Test.cpp 42  
Error   C2011   'student': 'class' type redefinition    Test    C:\Users\Projects\MSVC19\Tests\Test.cpp 35  
Message     see declaration of 'student'    Test    C:\Users\Projects\MSVC19\Tests\Test.cpp 26
```

If you change the name of struct (e.g. "struct _student {" and "_student stu;" both errors are solved as compiler looks in the right student class for constuctor declaration. So not the first error displayed it is the real culprit.